# How to access static method when using connect & HoC?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

To be able to fetch data for server-side rendering, it is [recommended](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html) to setup a static method `fetchData` which will populate the Redux store through async actions.

When using [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) the component is wrapped and is only accessible through `WrappedComponent`. However static methods are not accessible. The problem is further accentuated when using other HoC, such as `reducerInjector`. What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the react-redux docs you see that connect uses [hoistNonReactStatics](https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics) (and if you look in the source code, you'll find it in *connectAdvanced* which is then extended by *connect*).

So if you're using connect, you should still have access to your own static methods. However, if you're using other **HoCs**, the static methods **might** not be copied over.

Another option is to make your static method a function

```
export default myFunction = () => { /* do stuff */ }
```

and import it where you need to use it.

Comment: Following your answer I came across the following: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over

Comment: Glad i could help!